# Standard exception when a subclass' method implementation is missing?

Tags: java, exception, methods

### Context:

I have an abstract class `SuperClass`, which has a substantial number of subclasses, each working on a different business object, but in similar fashion.

I need to add some new functionality which definitely has its place in `SuperClass`, but will rely on a subclass-specific attribute, that I need to get in the superclass method. The obvious way here is to add an abstract getter in `SuperClass` for the attribute, and have every subclass override it so that it can send the correct attribute when called.

**The catch is: I am not allowed to change the code of other subclasses than the one I'm working on because of a fear of regressions**.

So I can't add an abstract method, as the other subclasses would not compile anymore.

Since only the object I'm working on now will require this new functionality, I can afford to declare a standard non-abstract method in `SuperClass`, and return `null` there. Then override it in the subclass I'm working on, and voilà.

### Question:

If someone who doesn't read my warnings in the Javadoc properly ever try to call this new method from a different subclass, it will produce unexpected results due to the getter not being properly overriden. Rather than returning `null` (and unexpected results) in `SuperClass`, I think throwing an exception would be more elegant and useful for my fellow programmers.

**I could define a custom-made exception, but does something along the lines of `YouForgotToImplementSomethingException` or `PleaseReadTheJavadocException` exists in the "standard" exceptions?**

### Edits:

Throwing an `Error` as suggested in an answer is not something I'm very fond of, but maybe here it could make sense to emulate the compiler's behavior? Thoughts on this?

Comment: You are absolutely right about Error. An application has no business throwing Error or subclasses of Error. They are for JVM errors that should be treated as fatal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have seen some libraries using [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) for this.

> Thrown to indicate that the requested operation is not supported.

Comment: IMHO, the "unsupported" means something different. It means that an implementation of an interface doesn't support some operations *by design*, e.g. a read-only collection throws the exception when you try to change/remove an element from it. Meanwhile the question states that code is wrong and should be changed, otherwise it produces *unexpected* results. So, the `AbstractMethodError` is more appropriate.

Comment: Moreover, the javadoc for the `UnsupportedOperationException` states "*This class is a member of the Java Collections Framework.*"

Comment: @kan - You may think that.  However, this is the exception that is *most commonly* used for this scenario.

Comment: A program should never throw an Error, an exception would be much better IMO.

Comment: I used the `UnsupportedOperationException`, in the end. Even if it wasn't specifically made for this scenario, it's close enough, and it's a `RuntimeException`, which is good, as I can avoid messing with all the method signatures.

Comment: What about `NoSuchMethodException` ("Thrown when a particular method cannot be found."), `IllegalAccessException` ("…but the currently executing method does not have access to the definition of the … method …") and `MissingResourceException(s, className, key)` ("Signals that a resource is missing.")?

Answer (score -2):

The exact thing is `java.lang.AbstractMethodError`.

Comment: No no no.  That means something different.  Besides, no application should be throwing subclasses of `Error`.

Comment: No the docs seem to be different that the present requirement IMO.

Comment: @StephenC As I understand the question, he needs an abstract method, but because of organizatoinal issues, he cannot do it. So, it means instead of using compiler to check it, he could throw the exception which jvm usually throws in very similar situation.

Comment: @kan - you clearly have not read the javadoc for the error.  If you did ... and you understood it ... you would understand that this is a completely different situation.  `AnstractMethodError` is thrown if a binary compatibility problem is detected at class load time.  It is a fatal error, and indicates that the JVM is in not in a fit state to continue running.  (BTW: it is NOT thrown by the compiler.  The compiler doesn't throw exceptions / errors ... unless there is a compiler bug).

Comment: @StephenC Huh... First of all, read more carefully. I've said that it is thrown by JVM, I know what compiler does and does not. Then, this is not *a* binary compatibility problem, it is *the* particular problem then parent's method suddenly becomes abstract, but children classes are not recompiled. And as stated in question, the method call *is* a fatal error, because could cause unexpected results, so the problem must be fixed. Meanwhile `UOE` just means the implementation doesn't do some operation and it is not an error, just undesired usage of an object.

Comment: @kan - I'm having difficulty understanding your English. Read JLS 13.4.16. which specifies the situation in which AME is thrown (and says that it is a binary compatibility error).  Now read the Question again, and not the OP specifically states that `abstract` cannot be used in the superclass; i.e. nothing "suddenly becomes abstract" in the OP's code.  What happens is that some class fails to override this method that *ought to be* abstract, but isn't because of the potential regressions.

Comment: @StephenC Do you know how to make a code throw the `AME` exception? It is easy - compile 2 classes, change a method to abstract, compile only this class, not recompiling the other. This is that binary incompatibility means, it happens often then you have incompatible libraries in a classpath. As I understand from the question, he wants an abstract method, but he cannot do it because "other subclasses would not compile anymore". The `AME` will do the deal: subclasses will compile, because the method is not abstract in fact, but in runtime it behaves as it is abstract.

Comment: @kan - yes I know all of that. I've used Java for 15+ years. Anyway, I finally understand what you are suggesting ... it won't work! He states that he CANNOT add the new method to all of the child classes, and he therefore CANNOT declare the method as abstract in Superclass. If he tried, the codebase would not compile - Regression. (And even if he fudged it by compiling old child classes against an old version of `Superclass`, the AME would be thrown when the old class was loaded.  Regression. So he'd be forced to change the old class anyway.)

Comment: @StephenC Yes, that's why I suggested to use the `AME` to throw. It will behave exactly the same as jvm would be: `int /*abstract*/ myNewMethod(){throw new AbstractMethodError("You must implement it!");}`

Comment: @kan - *"... that's why I suggested to use the AME to throw"*.  That brings us right back to my two original points.  1) The OP's situation is NOT a binary compatibility issue **as defined by the JLS**.  Therefore that is the wrong exception.  2) Application code throwing `Error` subclasses is wrong.

Comment: @StephenC 1) The JLS defines when the error is thrown by JVM. But it doesn't say it must be thrown by JVM only. If you read javadoc for `AME`, it says "if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed". As I understand, this is exact the same situation in the question. 2) Why? Any formal proof? In most cases it's just a bad practice because nobody should attempt to catch errors. And this situation is the case, and it is more specific and precise than `UOE`.

Comment: @kan - 1) Sophistry.  As I understand the situation is VERY different.  2a) Proof not required - most Java programmers think it is a bad idea. 2b) The difference between catch Exception and catch Throwable.  3) I'm tired of this argument.